# JPA date not show hour/minute/second

Tags: java, date, jpa

I have class with parameter Date.

```
@Temporal(javax.persistence.TemporalType.DATE)
@Column(name = DomainConstant.DOMAIN_LOGIN_LOG_DATE)
private Date date;
```

When I save object to db.

My date is not complete. In db is only `2016-02-03`, but why? How can I store full date in formate like `year-mouth-day hour-minute-second`?

Sure, I can use string, but how can I use date?

Comment: Use Timestamp instead of Date

Comment: Do you mean `Timestamp` from `java.sql.Timestamp;`?

Comment: @SheetalMohanSharma means to use `@Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)` instead.  This JPA annotation will give you the full date format.  It is equivalent to java.sql.Timestamp.

Answer (score 2):

Here is what you want to record the time as well as the date

```
@Temporal(javax.persistence.TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
    @Column(name = DomainConstant.DOMAIN_LOGIN_LOG_DATE)
    private Date date;
```